# rails s (WEBrick) results in stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting an error when starting WEBrick in development mode that I am having trouble tracing. In fact, I do not even know where to start. Since starting my current rails 4 project, WEBrick had been loading just fine. Now all of the sudden, it is throwing a stack level error. There has not been no major change to my code base that would explain this either since just a few hours ago the rails dev server was loading perfectly.

```
server:myapp n$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
bin/rails:4: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
server:myapp n$
```

Comment: Didn't it give you the line which caused the error?

Comment: Most of the time this happened to me when I had a loop inside a loop and so on like.. videos.each do |video| video.infos.each do |info| info.lines.each do |line| and so on. So if I was you I would think about what I changed.

Comment: @Pavan No. The server didn't even start.

Comment: @Evo_x On heroku the code runs fine in production.

Comment: The problem seems to be New Relic. I uninstalled the gem and now it works.

Comment: BTW Stack Level Too Deep basically means an `infinite loop`